# PointCut to match method annotated with certain params to the annotation

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj, pointcut

I have this PointCut

```
@Pointcut("execution(@com.foo.bar.aspect.annotation.MyAnnotation* * (..))"
          + "&& @annotation(annot)")
public void anyFoo(MyAnnotation annot)
{

}
```

`MyAnnotation` looks like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation
{
   boolean isFoo();

   String name;
}
```

Let's say I annotate a method with this annotation with isFoo set to true

```
@MyAnnotation(isFoo = true, name = "hello")
public void doThis()
{
   System.out.println("Hello, World");
}
```

How do I write my pointcut so that it matches only method annotated with `MyAnnotaion` AND `isFoo = true`?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
@Pointcut("execution(@com.foo.bar.aspect.annotation.MyAnnotation(isFoo = true, *) * * (..))"
          + "&& @annotation(annot)")
public void anyFoo(MyAnnotation annot)
{

}
```

Comment: This question is still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write a pointcut like this because AspectJ does not support it. You need to use something like

```java
@Pointcut("execution(@com.foo.bar.aspect.annotation.MyAnnotation* * (..))"
          + "&& @annotation(annot)")
public void anyFoo(MyAnnotation annot) {
    if (!annot.isFoo())
        return;
    // Only continue here if the annotation has the right parameter value
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for the same thought :D
Yeah, I thought of it, but I was just wondering if there's any better way to do it.